# How does a server detect a request made by Curl

Tags: curl

Go to ifconfig.me , now run "curl ifconfig.me". You get different responses. How does the server know how a request was made?

EDIT:
Here's a link that compliments the answer given below. It details the User-Agents curl uses. http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/curl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client passes information to the server in the request header. This includes, for example, the user agent string:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: ahaha can't believe I forgot about User agents. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing important thing, that one can set those headers manually.