# How to protect Node.JS web socket server against connection bomb?

Tags: security, node.js

Anyone can request to connect to my real-time application server written by Node.JS which started on port 80.

That means anyone can send large number of curl requests to bomb my socket server causes the connection overflow.
Any way to detect curl request and reject them?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is how to detect curl requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054695/how-does-a-server-detect-a-request-made-by-curl

Comment: Be aware that the post by Werner suggest looking at the user agent to detect cURL calls. This wouldn't be reliable for your scenario. Anyone can change the user agent and still submit bad requests and overload your server. You basically are trying to prevent a DoS attack.

Comment: Never heard the term 'connection bomb' before. This just sounds like DoS to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just depends on what kind of DDoS you are trying to prevent. For most situations HAProxy or IPTables should be sufficient:
HAProxy http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?10,452070

IPTables: http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/prevent-dos-with-iptables/